# Visa rules for South African nationals transiting through the US?

Tags: visas, transit, south-african-citizens

I am a South African travelling to Toronto, I have a visa for Canada  but my flight back is from Toronto to Washington DC Dulles international airport onward to OR Tambo in Johannesburg. Do I need another visa ?

Comment: I you have highly specific questions about South African nationals, you can always check here  https://community.justlanded.com/en/South-Africa/forum/Immigration-and-visa-advice

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, you will need a transit or C visa for the United States.

According to the [Department of State](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/other/transit.html) (emphasis mine):

> Generally, a citizen of a foreign country who wishes to enter the United States must first obtain a visa, either a nonimmigrant visa for temporary stay, or an immigrant visa for permanent residence. **Transit (C) visas are nonimmigrant visas for persons traveling in immediate and continuous transit through the United States enroute to another country, with few exceptions**.
>
> If you already have a valid visitor (B) visa, you may be able to use it to transit the United States. If you are a citizen of a participating country, you may be able to transit the United States on the [Visa Waiver Program](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/visit/visa-waiver-program.html).

South Africa isn't on the VWP list, so unless you happen to have a B type visa (tourism) you need to apply for a transit visa.